# Flutter: Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Tags: json, flutter

am very new at flutter. I try to read JSON files local. it still has a bug that I do not understand. it seems like

> itemCount: data.length

is not working for some reason. and I'm not sure that is because of this or not and I get the error like

> Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only
> valid value is 0: 1

And this is my code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:salomon_bottom_bar/salomon_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Room management',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Room management'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[400],
          title: Text(widget.title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 32,
              )),
          toolbarHeight: 70,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: ScrollConfiguration(
              behavior:
                  ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false),
              child: FutureBuilder(
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  var data = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return RoomCard(data[index]['roomNum'],
                          data[index]['peopleNum'], data[index]['price']);
                    },
                    itemCount: data.length,
                  );
                },
                future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                    .loadString('assets/data.json'),
              ),
            )),
        bottomNavigationBar: SalomonBottomBar(
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          onTap: (i) => setState(() => _currentIndex = i),
          items: [
            /// Home
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              title: Text("Home"),
              selectedColor: Colors.deepPurple[400],
            ),

            /// Likes
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
              title: Text("Likes"),
              selectedColor: Colors.pink,
            ),

            /// Search
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              title: Text("Search"),
              selectedColor: Colors.orange,
            ),

            /// Profile
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              title: Text("Profile"),
              selectedColor: Colors.teal,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget RoomCard(String roomNum, String peopleNum, String price) {
  return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 8),
    height: 91,
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
            spreadRadius: 1,
            blurRadius: 10,
            // offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
          ),
        ],
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 4, 16, 4),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("Room",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'WorkSans',
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Colors.deepPurple[400])),
                Text(roomNum,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'WorkSans',
                        fontSize: 48,
                        color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                        height: 0.95,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.people_alt,
                      color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                      size: 35.0,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 8,
                    ),
                    Text(peopleNum,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'WorkSans',
                            fontSize: 16,
                            color: Colors.deepPurple[400])),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Text("Price: " + price + " Baht",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'WorkSans',
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.deepPurple[400])),
          ),
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.settings_outlined,
                    color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                    size: 35.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ))
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

And this is it shown on the simulator.
[error on simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksmfv.png)

this is my JSON file

```
[
    {
        "roomNum": "101",
        "peopleNum": "1",
        "price": "3,500"
    },
    {
        "roomNum": "102",
        "peopleNum": "1",
        "price": "3,500"
    }
]
```

Comment: Share you `json`.

Comment: oh sorry, i updated it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to this.

```
Future<String> getData() async {
    String data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
    return data;
  }

  var _currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[400],
          title: Text(
            'widget.title',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 32,
            ),
          ),
          toolbarHeight: 70,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: ScrollConfiguration(
            behavior:
                ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false),
            child: FutureBuilder(
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  var data = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return RoomCard(data[index]['roomNum'],
                          data[index]['peopleNum'], data[index]['price']);
                    },
                    itemCount: data.length,
                  );
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
              future: getData(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

your get the error because your widget build, before `FutureBuilder` get the data from device.
you should always put your code inside `if(snapshot.hasData){YOUR CODE}`. otherwise the `snapshot.data` returns `null`

Comment: Sorry for late response. i was working.

Comment: thankful a lot, LUV <3

Answer (score 0):

You're parsing data to string, should be an array to get the length property.